# Get the X rows with most repeated records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was wondering on how can I get the X number of elements with the most repeated elements on a table. For example, on a table like:

ID* | ID_USER | ID_PRODUCT | ACCESS_DATE

- ID is the primary key.
- ID_USER can be repeated meaning that the most rows we can find with that user ID, the most products he bought.

What I want to get is, for example, **the 5 users who bought the most products.**

Comment: select ID_USER, count(1) as total from table group by ID_USER order by total desc limit 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregate function count ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html ) with GROUP BY

```
SELECT ID_USER, count(*) as num_b 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY ID_USER
ORDER BY num_b DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)